# Why does this example involving std::accumulate compile (badly), and how to guard against misuse?

Tags: c++, floating-point, compiler-flags, coercion, accumulate

Surprinsingly (for me), this compiles:

```
    std::vector<int> v;
    std::accumulate(std::cbegin(v), std::cend(v), 0, [](double sum, auto i){
        return sum + 0.1;
    });
```

(gcc 12 with --std=c++20a)

This is bad, because if I look at the signature of `std::accumulate`, it returns what's passed in the `init` argument, which in my case is the ***integer*** 0. But obviously, the passed lambda works with (takes and returns) doubles. So there must be some double to int coercion happening somewhere, that the compiler, surprinsingly, allows.

To ensure proper behavior, my code now reads `std::accumulate(std::cbegin(v), std::cend(v), 0.0,...`, (notice the 0.0). But this is unsatisfactory because next time when I'm less careful, I will write just 0 not 0.0.

I would like to know why does GCC allow this and is there a way (I suspect a compiler flag) to prevent this from compiling?

Comment: The original code is valid and its meaning is well defined. Any compiler that refuses to compile it does not conform to the C++ language definition.

Comment: `[](double& sum, auto i)` will cause the compiler to be grumpy with the mismatch.

Comment: I'm glad `std::accumulate` allows this behavior.  This is a feature, not a bug.  You can accumulate to any type, even if the type doesn't match the container type.  One classic example is this `std::vector<int> v; std::accumulate(v.begin(), v.end(), std::string(), []...)` and you want to stick a comma between the values.

Comment: In C++20, you can replace the parameter type `double` with `std::same_as<double> auto` to forbid any implicit conversions to `double`.   [demonstration](https://godbolt.org/z/6roYMKo1z)

Comment: In C++14, you can replace the parameter type `double` with `auto` and then `static_assert` that the type is correct.  [demonstration](https://godbolt.org/z/f6hGrz37W)

Comment: *and how to guard against misuse?* -- Maybe for your use case, it would be considered "misuse".  But let's say you wanted a template function that will "accumulate" values in a container to a string (take the comma string, for example), whether the container is int, double, char, etc.  Also let's say you want to stick with the "no `for`-loop" way of programming.  Using `std::accumulate`, where the initializer type is `std::string` allows you to do this, regardless of the types that are in the container.  So in this case, you do *not* want to match the initial value type to the container type.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie The goal in this case is not to match the initial type with the container type, but to match the initial type with the return type of the accumulating operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the defined behavior of `std::accumulate`. It will initialize the accumulator with the initial value provided and take on its type. Then it will repeatedly add new values with the accumulator, always assigning the intermediate results to the accumulator object. The assignment coerces the `double` result of the lambda into a `int` (the type of the accumulator). This is allowed, because C++ always allows implicit `double`-to-`int` conversion. Similarly while adding, the current value of the accumulator will be implicitly converted to `double` to fit the lambda's parameter.

`std::accumulate` is not defined to perform any check on the types so that no such conversion happens. If you want that, you will need to write your own wrapper around `std::accumulate` enforcing these constraints, for example:

```
// doesn't cover some edge cases

// prevents only conversion in the accumulator assignment
// not in the `op` arguments

template<typename It, typename T, typename O>
T my_accumulate(It first, It last, T init, O op) {
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(op(std::move(init), *first)), T>, "Incompatible init type!");
    return std::accumulate(first, last, init, op);
}
```

The lambda may also be used to enforce stricter typing in various ways. The comments under the question list some possibilities:

- Use `double&` instead of `double` as type. This enforces that the accumulator has type `double`, because otherwise the reference cannot bind to it. However, `const double&` or `double&&` won't work, since these are allowed to bind to temporaries, which would again be created implicitly.
- Declare the type as `auto` instead of `double`. This will guarantee that the type is deduced to the type of the accumulator. Then `static_assert` with `std::is_same` that it is deduced to `double`.
- (Since C++20) Declare the type as `std::same_as<double> auto` instead of `double` which has the same effect as above, but instead of a hard failure during instantiation it will cause overload resolution on the lambda to fail due to constrain violation.

As far as I know there is no warning flag in common compilers that could warn about this, because the conversion happens in an implicit instantiation from a template, where e.g. the `-Wconversion` flag and similar warning flags are usually not applied to avoid too much noise.

Comment: the answer addresses the right issue. 
"because C++ always allows implicit double-to-int conversion"
is there a GCC flag which turns this off?

Comment: @haelix There is e.g. the `-Wconversion` warning flag (which can be turned into an error with `-Werror`), but such warning flags are usually not applied to instantiations from templates, because that would generate too much noise. Completely disabling these implicit conversions would break most C++ code. They have been there since the beginning of C.